# Installing git onto a VM running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to clone a repository in Git onto my VM that has Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

When I try and run the git clone I receive an error that Git is not installed..
[git clone "https..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbgSe.png)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or why I'm unable to install git.  Any information would be helpful on how to install git, or to get past the error:

```
"The following packages have unmet dependies:
git: Depends: liberror-perl but it is not isntallable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

**EDIT:**

In response to @NimrodArgov.  I can't post more than 2 links since I have less than 10 reputation points.

So I have deleted one of the older links.  See:
[sudo apt-get update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQFm.png)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/819171/unable-to-install-git-package-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Could it be a simple case of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @NimrodArgov I have tried sudo apt-get update.  I've Edited the post to contain the screenshot of what my result is.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this problem because Ubuntu is installed as a VM and therefore it may have problems to connect to the internet.

Things to check:
* The network config of the VM.
* The firewall on the host.
* The apt.conf on ubuntu.

The following answers my help you: [answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711889/err-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-14-04) [answer 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336870/i-cannot-use-apt-get-update)

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the package

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove <package name>
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

If doesn't work :

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install GIT :

```
sudo apt-get install git
```